# Where is force_login() in Kohana 3.2 Auth class?

Tags: kohana, authentication

And if it's gone what I should do to emulate this function? Auth base on ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using file driver there is force_login function in https://github.com/kohana/auth/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/auth/file.php on line 59

And if you are using ORM, function is in https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/auth/orm.php on line 123.

Comment: I found it. My IDE (PHPStorm) don't show this fund in complete list :(